# Pull out garbage drawer doesn’t pull out fully. How can I fix it?

Tags: custom-cabinetry

I don’t know the brand of the pull out mechanism, but for years it’s never fully pulled out without exerting a lot of force. Any idea what was installed wrong and how to fix it?

Here’s some pictures:
[image] [image]

and a video: https://imgur.com/a/HxNgjnF

Comment: imgur is not working right now, but I would check all the screws are tight to the wall and one is not not causing binding/sticking out a touch more.

Comment: the screws are tight from what I can tell… Once I pull it fully out, it stays smooth for a while. Not sure if that’s a day or a week. But at some point it gets stuck again and I have to use a lot of force to pull it fully out again.

Comment: The answer below seems correct, but run your fingers over the screws carefully.  All should be smooth/the same feeling.  Do the same for the track/guides and wheels.  Be careful of nicks.

Comment: Possibly there is some crud in tracks that messes with the balls or rollers

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me, @crip659. I was thinking that maybe work had blocked it (it's been working at home).

Comment: @FreeMan  It seems to be a firefox problem, maybe ad blocker.  It works with opera and VPN

Comment: Hrm... I use FireFox & Brave at home with a VPN. At the office It's not working with FF, Brave or Chrome, and they've blocked most extensions, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the pullout wasn't installed incorrectly (in other words it used to slide easily but isn't now), the slides may need a bit of silicone grease or oil. There are linear ball bearings in the slides, and if these bearings get full of dust and dirt or are cleaned too much after being thus dirtied, the grease installed by the slide's factory may be gone, and needs replenishing.

I cannot recommend a particular grease, but some reasonable silicone grease and a cotton swab can get the slidiness back into the slides. (A little motor oil and a swab worked great for my bathroom's pocket door slide.)

Comment: It slides correctly for a while once it is forcefully opened. Then after a while it stops opening fully again. It’s very strange behavior to me. 
Right now, since I forced it open, it works like a champ. Closes smoothly and opens fully. But soon it will stop opening fully again.

Comment: Sounds like the same thing I saw in my old cabinet shop job, when the fine wood dust accidentally settled on old drawer slides: the slide could be forced open and would work OK at least partway, but needed cleaning and relubricating to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few years back. It turned out that the spacing of the tracks was not even but sort of bulged and the glide wheel would bind.